# Azure Maps Routing provides No Traffic Delay Information

Tags: azure-maps

When I post this request in Postman to Azure Maps Routing (Key Removed)

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?subscription-key=xxx&api-version=1.0&query=50.7950853432162,-1.1176335811615:50.8494396228343,-1.06779478490353&departAt=2019-01-31T07:30:00&travelMode=car&&traffic=true
```

I get this response (just the summary posted).

```
    "routes": [
    {
        "summary": {
            "lengthInMeters": 19388,
            "travelTimeInSeconds": 2146,
            "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
            "departureTime": "2019-01-31T07:30:00Z",
            "arrivalTime": "2019-01-31T08:05:46Z"
        },
```

I know that there should be a traffic delay of about 30 mins on this particular route. Why no traffic delay?

Comment: Just a heads up that I passed this on to the Azure Maps team for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TrafficDelayInSeconds returns the delay in seconds caused by the real-time incident(s). Delay in seconds is compared to the conditions according to real-time traffic information. 
travelTimeInSeconds value already includes the delay due to traffic, calculated by using time-dependent historic traffic data. If you add the parameter **'computeTravelTimeFor=all'** to your request, response will include travel times for all types of traffic information and specifies all results in the fields noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds, historicTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds and liveTrafficIncidents being included in the summaries in the route response.

In the example below travelTimeInSeconds equals to historicTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds and trafficDelayInSeconds is calculated using time-dependent historic traffic data.

```html
"summary": {
                "lengthInMeters": 8446,
                "travelTimeInSeconds": 728,
                "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                "departureTime": "2019-01-02T19:06:15Z",
                "arrivalTime": "2019-01-02T19:18:22Z",
                "noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds": 606,
                "historicTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds": 728,
                "liveTrafficIncidentsTravelTimeInSeconds": 728
}
```

Here is an real-time routing request response that returns trafficDelaysInSeconds >0:

```html
{
            "summary": {
                "lengthInMeters": 2131,
                "travelTimeInSeconds": 274,
                "trafficDelayInSeconds": 37,
                "departureTime": "2019-01-02T20:00:37Z",
                "arrivalTime": "2019-01-02T20:05:11Z",
                "noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds": 204,
                "historicTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds": 238,
                "liveTrafficIncidentsTravelTimeInSeconds": 274
            },
```